# Как добавить удалить класс при скролле в нужном месте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В разметке есть три блока, которые при скролле должны меняться. Т.е. на определенной высоте к div'у добавляем класс, при дальнейшей прокрутке после добавления класса допустим на 100px удаляем класс. Реализовать добавления класса не проблема, а вот удалить класс на заданной высоте не получается. 
Если использовать `else $('.news1').removeClass('active');` то этот вариант не подходит т.к. класс добавляется после определенный высоты прокрутки и удаление происходит при меньшей заданной высоте прокрутки.

```
<div class="news news1 wrap-b2-txt">
    <h6>lorem</h6>
    <p>lorem lorem lorem</p>
</div>
<div class="news news2 wrap-b2-txt">
    <h6>lorem</h6>
    <p>loremloremloremlorem</p>
</div>
<div class="news news3 wrap-b2-txt">
    <h6>lorem</h6>
    <p>loremloremloremlorem</p>
</div>

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 900) {
        $('.news1').addClass('active');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1000) {
        $('.news3').addClass('active');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1100) {
        $('.news3').addClass('active');
    }
)};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Предложили задать диапазон высоты в if как это написать:?

Comment: @Дмитрий неправильно закрыты скобки в конце. Поменяйте местами фигурную и круглую. Пример, что Вы хотите сделать ниже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как пример:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  ($(window).scrollTop() > 500 && $(window).scrollTop() < 900)?
    $('.some-block').addClass('some-class'):
  $('.some-block').removeClass('some-class');
});
```

```css
*,*:after,*:before{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;margin:0;outline:0}
/*стили выше добавлены только для этого примера, в реальном проекте не использовать*/
html, body, .wrapper-scroll-field, .some-block{
  width:100%
}

.wrapper-scroll-field{
  position:relative;
  height:2000px;
}

.some-block{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translatey(-50%);
      -ms-transform:translatey(-50%);
          transform:translatey(-50%);
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}

.some-class{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-scroll-field">Scroll Down
  <div class="some-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да это именно то, что я искал